# How to reduce the length jenkins pipeline script?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am using the pipeline script to build the jobs parallel when parameter matches, but for each parameter it builds upto 10 to 15 jobs parallely, so the code comes around nearly length 450 lines. is that any way to reduce the code or any other way to configure and build the job?

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

pipeline {

agent any

    parameters {

        choice(
                choices: 'Job1\nJob2'\nJob3,
                description: '',
                name: 'Project'
        )
    }
 stages {
       stage ('callJob1') {

        when {
             expression { params.Project == 'Job1' }
        }
        steps{
            build job: 'test1'
            build job: 'test2'
            .
            .
            .
            .
            .
            }
        }    
      stage('callJob2'){

      when{
            expression { params.Project == 'Job2'}
      }
      steps{
            build job: 'test3'
            build job: 'test4'
            .
            .
            .
            .
            .
            }
      }
      stage('callJob3'){

      when{
            expression { params.Project == 'Job3'}
      }
      steps{
            build job: 'test5'
            build job: 'test6'
            .
            .
            .
            .
            .
            }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: `[1..430].each{i-> build job: "test${i}" }`

Comment: may i know how this is work?

Comment: In case if your jobs are numbered you could form the array and execute build in a loop

Comment: or you can do it like this: `'''test1 test2 test11 test22'''.split(' +').each{i-> build job: i}`

Comment: Hi, @Nail did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try extract common parts in steps and define methods in the jenkinsfile. Methods defined in jenkinsfile A can also be called in jenkinsfile B in same project.

ex:

```
   def func() {
   }

   .
   .
   stages {
       stage('Job1'){
           steps {
               script {
                   func()
               }
           }
       }
       stage('Job2'){
           steps {
               script {
                   func()
               }
           }
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use [scripted](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#scripted-pipeline) syntax instead of the declarative one. Scripted versions tend to be more concise and dynamic. While declarative syntax was introduced **after** the scripted one, it is not necessarily better.

```
properties([
   parameters([
      choice(
          choices: 'Job1\nJob2'\nJob3,
          description: '',
          name: 'Project'
      )
   ])
])

stage('callJob1') {
   if (params.Project == 'Job1') {
      build job: 'test1'
      build job: 'test2'
   }
}

stage('callJob2') {
   if (params.Project == 'Job2') {
      build job: 'test3'
      build job: 'test4'
   }
}
```

Not to mention, you can do a lot of neat tricks thanks to the scripted nature (which you can't normally do in declarative mode). For example "generating" stages dynamically or setting job properties dynamically: while in declarative mode you can't pre-calculate and *then* pass job `parameters`, here you can pass elements in form or a regular List to `properties` (for example: set of parameters depend on the name of the branch)

Also no repetitive boilerplate blocks of agent, when, expression etc.
IMO scripted syntax is far easier if you are familiar with programming and would like to take maximum benefit that code can provide to you.